# Get and apply printer permissions from print server to printer

Tags: powershell, printing

I successfully wrote a powershell script to pull and apply permissions from one printer to all the other printers on the server now I need to pull permissions from the print server and apply them to all printers on the server. See the attached screenshot for clarification. Through all my research I haven't found anything that will help me out.

[image]

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: I don't know enough to go into much detail, but have you considered pulling the ACLs, and applying the ACLs? See commands like Get-Acl